# What literary device is this? A. B. C

Tags: literary-techniques, literary-device

Asyndeton refers to a practice in literature whereby the author purposely leaves out conjunctions in the sentence, while maintaining the grammatical accuracy of the phrase.

Example:

1. Read, Write, Learn.
2. Watch, Absorb, Understand.
3. Reduce, Reuse, Recycle.

Source: [Literary Devices](http://literary-devices.com/content/asyndeton)

If we replace the commas with periods what device would it be, if any?

1. Read. Write. Learn.
2. Watch. Absorb. Understand.
3. Reduce. Reuse. Recycle.

Comment: Perhaps a bulleted list with the bullets misplaced.

Comment: They're simply three-part lists, which I have heard described as the most powerful tool in the English language… though I don't recall by whom.

Answer (score 1):

The examples with colons are known as **tricolons**, which are a type of [isocolon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isocolon). The most famous tricolon is probably Julius Caesar's

> [Veni, vidi, vici](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veni,_vidi,_vici) [I came; I saw; I conquered]

Replacing the colons with full stops can be a way of creating longer pauses between the individual parts of the tricolon. I'm not aware of a name for this literary device.

As Rob_Ster pointed out in a comment, "veni, vidi, vici" is also an example of a [**asyndeton**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asyndeton), which Wikipedia defines as "a figure of speech in which one or several conjunctions are omitted from a series of related clauses." (But the link in the question already referenced a page about "asyndeton".)

Comment: One could probably accuse the speaker of *asyndeton* as well.

Comment: @Rob_Ster Thanks. I had forgotten about that, so I have now updated my answer.